# List or Dictionary or something else?

Tags: c#, dictionary, argumentexception

I want to save some coordinates in a dictionary, BUT the xPos should be twice or more in the dictionary.

The problem is that the following exception appears:
`ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.`

How can I solve the problem ?

I allready thought that I can use a List or an Array, but I want a Key and a Value.

After I saved the coordinates in a Dict (or something else) I want to check whether a new coordinate is a certain distance of the existing ones.

The xPos is allways the same:
There is a "chart" where I place some blocks in a row with different yPos.
1. Block: xPos = 0, yPos = random
2. Block: xPos = 1, yPos = random
...
n. Block: xPos = 80, yPos = random
n+1. Block: xPos = 0, yPos = 20 + random

I have three iterations, for each 80 Blocks are placed.

[image]

SORRY for my bad english :|
I hope you could understand.

Comment: Do you want to associate multiple `Y` values with one `X` value?

Comment: No. I want to save multiple Points which have the same xPositions.

Comment: I don't think you want a `Key`/`Value` then

Comment: I want a Key Value association, because when I check whether the new Block is a certain distance away from another Block, I can use the key to check the value.

Comment: what's wrong with a list of `Point`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use `List` of [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store list of `int`-`int` pairs without creating new class and without worrying about duplicate values :

```
.....
List<Tuple<int, int>> blocks = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
blocks.Add(Tuple.Create(0, random));
blocks.Add(Tuple.Create(1, random));
.....
```

Comment: Is it the same as `List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>` ? If it is I think it's a better solution then to use a struct.

Comment: yes, both are almost the same in this case. Only `Tuple` can handle more than pair, f.e `Tuple<int, int, int, int>`, etc (doesn't seems to be a feature you need for now though)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class (or a struct) to keep and use your coordinates, instead of a dictionary.
The class can have Key and Value properties and also additional fields if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the values like List, where Position contains:

```
public int X { get; set; }
public int Y { get; set; }
```

Or you can use some another class/struct from C# or some 3rd libraries (2d vector, point, etc) depends on where you want to use it. :)

Comment: I think a struct is the easiest way. But first I need to google how its works.

Comment: Well a struct is such as an class, isnt it? so that I have to create x-objekts associatied to the amount of block?!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're storing points in a 2-d surface and want to do nearest-point detection, I'd recommend using a [Binary Space Partitioning (BSP) tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning), such as a QuadTree. Here's a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30535/A-Simple-QuadTree-Implementation-in-C) to a quadtree implementation in C#.